# How to execute ISPF commands through rexx(MF)

Tags: mainframe

Suppose I want to call the ispf commands(like sar,fild in command lines which displays the respective screens) through my tool. Can anyone provide me a basic code to access sar screen through my tool

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Address" verb to target the ISPEXEC environment.  If done as a simple "Address ISPEXEC", is switches the default target environment to ISPF.  Alternatively, you can use the form "Address ISPEXEC command" to route a single command to ISPF.

ISPEXEC is the Dialog Services environment, there is also the ISREDIT environment for dealing with the ISPF editor specifically.

Some great references on this would be the "ISPF Services Guide" and "ISPF Edit and Edit Macros".  Both are freely available from IBMs book server.